# how to make a regex to validate a username

Tags: regex, validation

I've written this regex

```
/(?=.*[a-z])(?!.*[A-Z])([\w\_\-\.].{3,10})/g
```

to check the following conditions

```
>has minimum of 3 and maximum of 10 characters.
>must contain atleast a lowercase alphabet.
>must contain only lowercase alphabets, '_', '-', '.' and digits.
```

this works but returnes true even if there is more than 10 characters.

I would like a new or modified regular expression to check the above given conditions.

Comment: Did you try starting your regex with `^` and ending it with `$` ?

Comment: Changed the regex to "/^((?=.*[a-z])(?!.*[A-Z])([\w\_\-\.].{3,10}))$/". Every condition is being checked, but it is allowing other characters than words, digits, '_' , '-' and '.'

Comment: Do you have to use regex ? The at least a lowercase letter looks pretty annoying to implement that way

Comment: I'm learning regex so tried to write it all in one line and it works. But I'm open to new suggestions.

Comment: But the only problem is if I input "6749m&" it's returning True. Which is supposed to be false because only allowed special characters are '- ', '_ ', '.'

Comment: You're putting `.{3,10}` at the end of your regex so it can match any character between 3 and 10 times. `/[a-z_-.]{3,10}/` would probably work better but you lose the atleast condition

Comment: What if I write it both as different expressions and use a AND operator on it's result? So it would be only vaid  if both of the regex return true

Comment: Yes, this should be way easier. You can test `/^[a-z_-.]{3,10}$/` and `/[a-z]/`, I think it should work

Comment: Oh I'll try that for sure. Btw as I'm a new guy to regex which is a Better practice - writing all condition in one line or writing separate line for each condition- ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add hanchors
2. remove the last dot
3. the negative lookahead is useless is you use a correct character class

This regex will work:

```
 ^(?=.*[a-z])[a-z0-9_.-]{3,10}$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/NITGlk/1)

Comment: @NaveenKR: You're welcome, glad it helps. You also may upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this REGEX

[REGEX Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eUJYeb/3)

```
([a-z]{1}[0-9a-z_.-]{2,9})
```

, Tried text

```
username77
usr
username10
user_test
usr.1000
```

Comment: This doesn't match `123a456` but it should.

Comment: let me check that

Comment: Can the pattern start with numbers?

Comment: OP didn't make a condition on this.

Comment: `[a-z]{1}` is the same as `[a-z]` but there is no requirement that the string start with a letter. You should revise or delete your answer.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways of doing this. I believe the common characteristic is they will all have a positive lookahead. Here is another.

```
^(?=.{3,10}$)[a-z\d_.-]*[a-z][a-z\d_.-]*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ldKSXO/2/)

Notice that `[a-z\d_.-]*` appears twice. Some regex engines support subroutines (or subexpressions) that allow one to save a repeated part of the regex to a numbered or named capture group for reuse later in the string. When using the PCRE engine, for example, you could write

```
^(?=.{3,10}$)([a-z\d_.-]*)[a-z](?1)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ldKSXO/3/)

`(?1)` is replaced by the regex tokens that matched the string saved to capture group 1 (`[a-z\d_.-]*`), as contrasted with `\1`, which references the content of capture group 1. The use of subroutines can shorten the regex expression, but more importantly it reduces the chance of errors when changes are made to the regex's tokens that are repeated.